# ABI derived JSON in the "data" parameter of a raw transaction

Tags: json-rpc, abi, raw-transaction, rpc

This is what I have so far, please correct me if I'm wrong:

The `data` parameter of a transaction is where we tell a deployed smart contract how we want to interact with it.
It contains a hexed JSON containing all the input for all the functions of the contract we want to interact with.
This JSON is coded using the contract's ABI, which is kind of a manual on what formats the contract can take and will return.
To fit in the `data` parameter, the JSON we want to send must be turned into hex.

Assuming all this is right, I'm looking for examples of non-hexed `data` JSONs to get a grasp on what I'm suposed to write using the ABI.

Comment: Please rephrase the questions, in my opinion in can mean 2 things. Just to be more clear so we can help

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not a programmer. Basically I wanna know how to writte data input using a contract's ABI (if it makes sense to do such a thing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is not a hexadecimal representation of JSON data. Solidity has a custom format, described in the [Contract ABI Specification](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.7/abi-spec.html). Essentially there are two different types of types, static and dynamic. Static types are types that always fit in 32 bytes (= 256 bits) of data, like `uint256`, `address`, etc. Dynamic types are types that don't fint in this 32 bytes of data, like `bytes`, `string` and arrays (including things like `uint256[]`).

Static types are encoded in the same order as your Solidity function. So let's say we have a function like this:

```
function foo(uint256 bar, address baz) external
```

The transaction `data` field starts with the function selector, specifying which function to call. In this case that's `a68b44f8` (the first four bytes of the Keccak hash of `foo(uint256,address)`. After that we put the values of `bar` in `baz` in that order, where each value is 32 bytes long. If we want to encode `12345` for `bar` and `0x4bbeeb066ed09b7aed07bf39eee0460dfa261520` for `baz`, the data becomes:

```
0xa68b44f8 (function selector)
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003039 (bar)
0000000000000000000000004bbeeb066ed09b7aed07bf39eee0460dfa261520 (baz)
```

In the case of dynamic types, we encode a pointer to dynamic value instead. The value is appended to the end of the data, starting with the length of the value (32 bytes). So if we have a function like this:

```
function foo(uint256[] bar, address baz) external
```

And we want to encode `[12345, 67890]` for `bar` and the same address for `baz`, the data becomes:

```
0xd22ec959
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000040 (pointer to bar)
0000000000000000000000004bbeeb066ed09b7aed07bf39eee0460dfa261520 (baz)
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002 (length of bar)
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003039 (bar[0])
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010932 (bar[1])
```

The Contract ABI Specification describes how different types in Solidity should be encoded. I wrote a more detailed explanation of transaction data which you can find [here](https://medium.com/mycrypto/why-do-we-need-transaction-data-39c922930e92).

Comment: Thank you very much, you've cleared most of my doubts.

Answer (score 0):

```
var sample_contract_instance = await new web3.eth.Contract(<CONTRACT_ABI>, <CONTRACT_ADDRESS>);
var sample_contract_method = await sample_contract_instance.methods.testMethod(<SAMPLE_PARAM_1>, <SAMPLE_PARAM_2>).encodeABI();

var transaction_object = {
    gasLimit: <SAMPLE_GAS_LIMIT>,
    from: <SAMPLE_ADDRESS>,
    nonce: <SAMPLE_NONCE>,
    chainId: 1,
    data: sample_contract_method,
    to: <CONTRACT_ADDRESS>
};
```

This is how you attach transaction data to transaction object, by encoding the contract method you wish to execute with `encodeABI()`.